# Secondary literature on "The Warden of the Tomb"

Tags: german-language, theater, franz-kafka, the-warden-of-the-tomb

*[The Warden of the Tomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warden_of_the_Tomb)* is an expressionist play fragment by Kafka. Although incomplete, possibly extremely so, it's still decently long - about fourteen pages. Sadly (to me at least), as far as I can tell it has received little attention: basically the only writing in English I can find on it are a [paper of Burç İdem Dinçel](http://static.dergipark.org.tr:8080/article-download/imported/1023001161/1023000977.pdf?) and a (medical!) [paper of Mishara](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2944142/). Even in German there seems to be little written on it, with the only example I can find being [a paper by Meinel](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43028077?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) *(although since I can't read German it's quite possible I've missed many)*.

However, I'm not particularly familiar with the field so my "literature search" has been essentially limited to just googling, and I'm well aware that there could be lots of great sources on the topic which aren't so easy to find.

I'm interested in whether there are other sources at least partially focusing on *Warden*. To avoid asking for a list of references, I'll phrase my question as:

> Is there "reasonably serious" secondary literature at least partially focusing on *Warden* other than the papers mentioned above? Failing that, where are places I might look for such literature?

I'm especially, although not exclusively, interested in sources in English (sadly, that's the only language I can read).

Comment: Incidentally, I can't comment on the quality of either of the linked papers, having not had time to read them.

Comment: Hi Noah, welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. I thought I was familiar with Kafka's work but I had never heard of *Der Gruftwächter* before reading your question. I think there are a few resources about that fragment. However, I would strongly recommend that you reword your question so it doesn't ask for a list of recommendations. That type of question is normally considered off-topic on our site. If you can make your question more specific, it should be OK.

Comment: @Tsundoku Thanks for letting me know. Would asking whether such sources exist, or where to search for such sources, be better? (My experience is in other SE sites, so I'm not yet used to the standards of this one.)

Comment: Asking whether any secondary literature (besides the papers you listed) can be on topic, especially if you can show what sort of research you have done already. Asking how to find such resources should also be OK. But anything that sounds like "please give me a list of X" would get closed as off topic.

Comment: @Tsundoku I definitely intended the question to be as you suggest. Has my edit improved the situation?

Comment: From my point of view, the constraints in your question (rather obscure play, even though the author is well known, secondary literature should be in English) are strict enough to make this acceptable.

Comment: Start with Meinel and then follow the references in the footnotes.

Comment: @GarethRees I tried that - unless I'm missing something, none of those sources focus specifically on *Warden*. The footnote sources all appear to be either broader literature on Kafka or Kafka's original writings. Do you see one I'm missing?

Comment: Footnotes 39 and 40 have promising titles.

Comment: @GarethRees That they do, and I missed them - thanks! However, I'm not getting much from them. Both articles are in German. Additionally, the articles (and the volumes they appear in) seem very hard to find: the Cersowsky article appears in the 1990 edition of GRM but the latter's website [only has issues back to 2012](https://grm.winter-verlag.de/journal/GRM), and I can't seem to find the volume the Ide article appears in at all.

Comment: So I'm still essentially in the dark. (As an aside, amusingly enough the volume ["Kafka's Narrative Theater"](https://books.google.com/books?id=3MxWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT113&lpg=PT113&dq=%22Jahrbuch+der+wittheit+zu+bremen+6%22&source=bl&ots=jbu6VP0OaO&sig=ACfU3U3VQJwTZyjIyKvAqp_hgghxB2EW5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiol8KHkoLpAhWTKs0KHfWjCkAQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=prince&f=false) which I found searching for the Ide article doesn't seem to ever mention *Warden*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are a few references in English:

- S. Zhao (2012): ["Kafka, Hamlet and the Modern Psyche's Ecology"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/298436747_Kafka_Hamlet_and_the_Modern_Psyche%27s_Ecology), Foreign Literature Studies, 34(1):152-159.

  From the abstract: "Shakespeare's Hamlet has special appeal to Franz Kafka, and the two have a deep spiritual relationship. The paper tries to use the relevant records in Kafka's diaries, letters and literary works, especially the play The Warden of the Tomb, to analyze this relationship. (...)"
- Andrew Zuliani: ["Kissing the Kolossoi: The Staging of Bare Life"](https://www.academia.edu/34917752/Kissing_the_Kolossoi_The_Staging_of_Bare_Life), December 2016. 
  This article discusses *The Warden of the Tomb* and other plays in the context of an analysis of Georgio Agamben’s *Homo Sacer: Sovereign Power and Bare Life* as a "theatrical text".
- Burç DİNÇEL: [REPRESENTING THE “OTHER” ON STAGE: A DRAMATURGICAL APPROACH TO FRANZ KAFKA'S “THE WARDEN OF THE TOMB” AND “THE HUNTER GRACCHUS”](https://studyres.com/doc/12863162/the-warden-of-the-tomb)
  (Also [available in Turkish](https://dergipark.org.tr/en/pub/teddergi/issue/18475/194540); already found by the OP.)
- Aaron L Mishara (2010): ["Kafka, paranoic doubles and the brain: hypnagogic vs. hyper-reflexive models of disrupted self in neuropsychiatric disorders and anomalous conscious states"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2944142/), Philosophy, Ethics and Humanities in Medicine, 2010; 5: 13. (One paragraph discussing the play; already found by the OP.)
- Peter F. Neumeyer: ["Franz Kafka, Sugar Baron"](https://search.proquest.com/docview/1301326282), Modern Fiction Studies, Vol. 17, Iss. 1,  (Spring 1971): 5. (This apparently *mentions* the play, but I can't access the full text to find out how much of the text discusses it.)
- Based on search engine results (see Rand al'Thor's comment), the following publication (or part of it) also appears to discuss *The Warden of the Tomb* but I have not been able to access an abstract or a preview to verify this:
  M. Lazar and R. Gottesman, Eds.: *The Dove and the Mole: Kafka's Journey Into Darknenss and Creativity* (*Interplay*, No. 5 (1987 or 1988, depending on the source, see e.g. [Open Library](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL8214705M/The_Dove_and_the_Mole))). (*Interplay* is or was series of conference proceedings published by [Undena](http://undena.com/INTER.html) and should not be confused with the [*Interplay* journal](http://interplay.thu.edu.tw/), which began in 2014.)

The footnotes to [Katharina Meinel's article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43028077) that Gareth Rees mentions in a comment contain references to articles in German (not in English); see Heinz Ide and Peter Cersowsky. It is somewhat easier to find German references than English ones:

- Heinz Ide: "Franz Kafka. Der Gruftwächter und Die Truppenaushebung. Zur religiösen Problematik im Kafka-Werk". Jahrbuch der Wittheit zu Bremen. Band 5 (1961): S. 11.
- Peter Cersowsky: "Kafkas philosophisches Drama: Der Gruftwächter". Germanisch-Romanische Monatsschrift, Band 40 (1990): S. 54-65.
- Sandra Fluhrer: ["Vorkehrungen gegen das Tragische: Die Gruftwächter-Fragmente"](https://brill.com/view/book/9783846760352/BP000011.xml). In Sandra Fluhrer's book [*Konstellationen des Komischen. Beobachtungen des Menschen bei Franz Kafka, Karl Valentin und Samuel Becket*](https://www.fink.de/view/title/52458?rskey=YrsCBy&result=1). Wilhelm Fink, 2016.

**Update**: *A Franz Kafka Encyclopedia* by Richard T. Gray, Ruth V. Gross, Rolf J. Goebel and Clayton Koelb (2005) has an entry on *Der Gruftwächter* which ends with a short "Further Reading" section that lists the articles by Peter Cersowsky, Heinz Ide and Katharina Meinel that are already listed above. It does not list any secondary literature in English.

Comment: Thanks for the Zhao article! (The Dincel and Mishara papers are mentioned in my question.)

Comment: I noticed after rechecking your question after I posted my answer :-(

Comment: Unfortunately the Zhao article is behind a paywall, but it looks quite interesting - hopefully I'll be able to get access to it at some point. Thanks again! (To others: I think the official site is [here](http://caod.oriprobe.com/order.htm?id=28794983&ftext=base).)

Comment: Registration on ResearchGate is free of charged (unless they changed that recently; it was free of charge when I registered).

Comment: I think that's right, but they don't seem to have the article (they have a "request full text" but IIRC that doesn't mean they actually have it?).

Comment: You're right; "request full text" means that it's not publicly available on the website and that you need to ask the author to provide it (a request they may ignore).

Comment: Searching Google Scholar in [English](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22the+warden+of+the+tomb%22&btnG=) and [German](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22Der+Gruftw%C3%A4chter%22&btnG=) gave a few more things: [a chapter in a book by Gottesman](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e492/db7352b53f97022f469fec53849ce99c1f48.pdf), some stuff in the middle of an article by Zuliani, articles by [Meinel](https://brill.com/view/journals/poe/27/3-4/article-p339_6.xml) and [Fluhrer](https://brill.com/view/book/9783846760352/BP000011.xml), and some citations.

Comment: Thank you very much for this list of sources!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks, that's quite interesting!